# Class member access using qualified-id in case of ambiguity

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, ambiguity

Consider a struct `B` derived from two structs `A<1>` and `A<2>`, each defining a typename `D` to itself, and there is also a global typename `D`. Then one writes `.D::` after a `B` object , which `D` must be taken?

```
template<int N> struct A{ int v = N; using D = A; };
struct B : A<1>, A<2> {};
using D = A<1>;
int main() { return B{}.D::v; }
```

According to the standard:
**[basic.lookup.classref]**

> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup.classref#4) If the id-expression in a class member access is a qualified-id of the form
>
> ```
> class-name-or-namespace-name::...
> ```
>
> the `class-name-or-namespace-name` following the `.` or `->` operator is first looked up in the class of the object expression ([class.member.lookup]) and the name, if found, is used. Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression.

So, first `D` must be looked inside struct `B`, but it is ambiguous there. And indeed, Clang reports an error about it:

```
error: member 'D' found in multiple base classes of different types
```

But GCC accepts the code, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/74qraoeac

It seems that GCC interprets the standard as if `D` is ambiguous in `B`, let us look outside of `B`. Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: I personally think Clang's behaviour seems correct here. You could try filing a bug against GCC and see if they agree.

Comment: Both are quite happy if one does `return B{}.::D::v;` instead. I'm leaning towards `clang++` being correct for looking for `D` in `B`  in the original code (before looking in the enclosing namespace where `D` is not ambiguous).

Comment: I agree with BrianBi. The quoted language says to look in another context only if the name is not found.  Well, the name is found, it is just ambiguous. The search should stop there.

Comment: Thanks, I reported GCC bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102170

Answer (score 2):

**Clang** is correct according to the recent clarification of that wording, which now says

> If nothing is found by qualified lookup for a member-qualified name that is the terminal name ([expr.prim.id.qual]) of a *nested-name-specifier* and is not dependent, it undergoes unqualified lookup.

Now there is no problematic “the name, if found” which could imply uniqueness.

Comment: How member-qualified name can be a terminal name?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: How is `D` here *not* the terminal name of `D::`?

Comment: Ok, then when a member-qualified name is not a terminal name?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: It’s always the terminal name of *something*; the question is of what.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.